# code runs well for small input but acts like an infinite loop when input is big

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve a problem which is to find prime bellow 2 millions and sum up them and show sum as my output(for more information see https://projecteuler.net/problem=10). I have written this code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int last_range;
    int not_prime_counter=0;
    int sum=0;
    int prime_number_counter=0;
    cout<<"Enter range from 2 to ";
    cin>>last_range;

    int input=2;
    /*
    if(input==1)
    {
    cout<<input<<" is Prime\n";
    sum=sum+input;
    input++;
    }
    */
    if(input==2)
    {
        cout<<input<<" Prime\n";

        sum=sum+input;
        cout<<"Sum : "<<sum<<endl;
        input++;
        prime_number_counter++;
    }
    if(input==3)
    {
        cout<<input<<" Prime\n";

        sum=sum+input;
        cout<<"Sum : "<<sum<<endl;
        input++;
        prime_number_counter++;
    }

    if(input>3)
    {
        for(int i=2;i<=(input/2);i++)
        {
            if(input==last_range)
            {
                break;
            }

            if(input%i==0)
            {
                //cout<<input<<" is NOT Prime\n";
                input++;
                i=2;
            }
            if(i==(input/2) && not_prime_counter==0)
            {
                cout<<input<<" Prime\n";

                sum=sum+input;
                cout<<"Sum : "<<sum<<endl;

                input++;
                i=2;

            }

        }
    }
    cout<<"Final Sum : "<<sum<<endl;



    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

It works well for 100,200 but when the input is 2000000 it runs forever. I want to know why this is happening and what is the solution for my problem? I want to use single for loop.

Comment: *"code runs well for small input but acts like an infinite loop when input is big"* That means your algorithm is slow :) It is not an infinite loop, it is just taking forever to do it's work.

Comment: See [this post](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46835/project-euler-problem-10-sum-of-primes-2mil) on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for suggestions on speeding up.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is much too slow for large inputs. To determine if a number is prime, you only need to check until its square root.

A clean and fast to check if a number is prime is:

```
bool prime(int n) {
  if (n == 1) return false;
  if (n == 2) return true;
  if (n % 2 == 0) return false;
  for (i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2)
     if (n % i == 0) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You should change the return type to `bool` and return `true`/`false`. It is fine as is since `int` has an implicit conversion to `bool`, but logically it should just return `bool` in the first place.